# Best Platform for building iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, mobile, cordova, titanium, appcelerator

Im looking into writing a fairly simple iPhone app and need some advice on the choice of platform. I have the following constraints:

**App Requirements:**

1. The app should be able to receive strings via a wifi network, process these and then display either a message, or show a preset photo from the library, or change the background color (or any combination of these).
2. Once started the app will be running continuously on the device, and be a display only client (ie no user interaction on the device itself) - just processing instructions as received over wifi.
3. Speed: once the strings are sent to the device, the app has to respond quickly (either display image, change color or show preset text as soon as possible.)

**My Current Situation:**

1. No previous iOS development experience.
2. I need to do this within the next 2 months.
3. I am very comfortable with: HTML, JS, CSS, Python & PHP.
4. I am familiar with other languages e.g. C++ but have not touched these in a long while.

**Question: Choice of Platform:**

I know that the best choice would be to use the native iPhone SDK, but given my time constraints and knowledge of existing tech, could tools such as [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) be proficient for this kind of application?

**Note:** At this stage I do not foresee the app being listed on the app store, its meant for personal use only, although this may change in the future.

Comment: Titanium is a great option. I doubt PhoneGap gives you access to many native device APIs...

Answer (score 1):

If it would be an option to load the images from a remote server instead of the local photo library and you being already familiar with HTML/JS/CSS/PHP, why not just make an Web-App that is running full-screen?

You can use your existing knowledge and you're saving money (no $99 license fee)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Björn. My main concern with web apps was speed. This needs to be as "real time" as possible. I am not certain if webapps can be as responsive as native apps. A friend also suggested looking into HTML5 websockets, so im looking into that now.

Comment: If you don't parse huge sets of data speed should not be the problem. I'm also not really sure if it's possible to "auto-pick" an image from the iPhone camera roll. I think this always needs to be done by the user using the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: After looking around a little, I'm beginning to lean towards a native app. The logic on the app itself isn't too difficult to implement, so should be a good chance to learn iOS development I think.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [TapLynx](http://taplynx.com/) - it's possible to create a native app without any code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do everything you want to do with Titanium. It even supports Sockets should you need to go to that raw of a level.  Native iOS development is painful and hideous.

Appcelerator is glorious and fun :]